# Include timezone information in WSDL date field

Tags: c#, date, datetime, soap, wsdl

I have a .NET model property in a SOAP message that has a data type of "date" (not datetime):

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="date")]
public System.DateTime DateField
{
    get
    {
        return this._dateField;
    }
    set
    {
        this._dateField = value;
    }
}
```

The WSDL for this part of the model is as follows:

```
<element minOccurs="0" name="DateField" type="xs:date" />
```

The requirement is that when this message is sent the timezone information is included.

When I am setting the DateField property I can see that the DateTimeKind is set to UTC. However when this message is sent via SOAP the recipient is only receiving the date (i.e. 2018-08-01) rather than the date with a timezone (i.e. 2018-08-01**T00:00:00+01:00**).

I have had a look at the XML schema on w3.org (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date) and it states that *"A "date object" is an object with year, month, and day properties just like those of dateTime objects, **plus an optional timezone-valued timezone property**."*

My question is how can I get this optional timezone property included in my SOAP XML instead of just the date, when I am already passing a DateTime with the timezone specified?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the attribute seems to work:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="date")]
```